# When adding controls from another assembly, they are automatically added to the icon list

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-forms-designer

Just a few days ago this started happening, and I'm not entirely sure why. When I add a control to my form (specifically from [here](https://github.com/viperneo/winforms-modernui)), it goes straight to the icon list, like where a timer would go.

[image]

Things I've tried:

- Uninstalling and reinstalling Visual Studio
- Installing another version of Visual Studio (tried 2010, 2012, 2013)
- Adding the control's project to my solution and using it that way instead of manually adding the controls to my toolbox from the compiled dll.

Nothing has worked so far, so right now I am at a loss. Should I just reformat and start fresh?

EDIT: I should clarify. When it's added to the list at the bottom, I cannot manually add it to the form or anything. If I change the Location property, it goes straight back to 0,0 and doesn't show up.

Comment: Is that a regular button or something else? It seems to me that it's a component (like a timer), not a control and that's why it goes to the component area.

Comment: @Gusman - It is a button. It was working before, but suddenly just started doing that.

Comment: Hmmm, I see "metroButton" in the name, may be it's an WPF control for Metro style apps and your app is a Desktop one?

Comment: I am using a metro theme for WinForms specifically. https://github.com/viperneo/winforms-modernui

Comment: Have you tried the example project at the repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MetroFramework.dll` requires that you also reference `MetroFramework.Design` in order to obtain design-time support.

```
[Designer("MetroFramework.Design.Controls.Metro...")]
...
public class MetroButton : Button, IMetroControl
```